# Horizontal scroll apears when I need to scroll site down

Tags: html, css

After creating some basic messy sites I motivated myself to do something better and responsive. And I've got a problem.

The problem is when my site has more height than 100vh and I need to scroll it down, then appeares horizontal scroll.

I tried changing units on containers, removing left/right paddings, margins in some places added `margin:0; padding:0;` in my 'reset.css' file and still I have no idea what can I do to fix it.
I know that I can use overflow but I read that actually it's not fixing but hacking and I want to know why this happens.

My site looks kinda like this. Not exacly but kinda, and as you see there is little space to slide horizontaly.

Sample code :

```
.container{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width:100vw;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zXLMPX

Also I'll be happy if u give me some advices/tips what I can do better in future, thank you!

Comment: Only add the relevant code in a SO snippet

Comment: Sorry it's my first post, also I don't know where exactly is the problem and didn't want to post whole css in thread.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from the fact that you haven't normalized your HTML yet. HTML naturally has some padding and margin. You should *almost* always remove this with the universal selector at the beginning of a project. You can also remove it from the `html` or `body` tags directly.

Here is a snippet without removing the default margin/padding:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Here is a snippet removing the margin/padding using the universal selector:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! But I forgot to add that I already add   margin: 0; and
  padding: 0; to * in my css file 'reset.css' which I attach to html file.

Comment: You're likely not linking that file correctly then, or your Codepen example isn't the same code. Adding `margin: 0` to your Codepen gives the desired outcome. See [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVBqPO).

Comment: I didn't linked reset.css to codepen that's why there were margins/padding, but I linked it to file on my computer and it works well. And as you see in code you send me there is no right border on container (blue one) which means there is some space behind it. Horizontal scroll just doesn't appear because of overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the margin on your `body` tag it should remove the horizontal scroll:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Alternatively you can use `overflow-x: hidden` to always hide the horizontal scroll.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But I forgot to add that I already add margin: 0; and padding: 0; to * in my css file 'reset.css' which I attach to html file

Answer (score 0):

On your container use
     `.container { width: 100%; }`

the issue might also be with how codepen displays your page.

If you want to disable horizontal scroll entirely you can always do this
`body { overflow-x: hidden; }`

Comment: Thank you for answer but adding 100% width to container isn't work. I think it's just equal to 100vw. Codepen display page well because I have the same size horizontal slider on my browser. Yeah I'll probably use this overflow but I'd love to find out why this happens:/